Is there any better way to get existential type's actual type in lldb
protocol Car {
    func printCar()
}

struct SportsCar : Car {
    func printCar() {

    }
}

func generateSportsCar() -> any Car {
    return SportsCar()
}

func test() {
    let obj = generateSportsCar()
    obj.printCar()
}

the  generateSportsCar is return a existential type (any car) , But if I print the obj in the lldb :
Printing description of obj:
testSwiftProj.SportsCar()

It says the type is the concrete type SportsCar , not the existential type like any< Car > or something else , what 's the best way to get the existential type in lldb ?

I can even call the method of SportsCar with obj, what do you mean with this?

I don't see an actual question in your post. What are you asking about?

@Sweeper my problem is my function return a existential type , and lldb print is the type is not a existential type but a concrete type

@JoakimDanielson I mean if the obj is a existential type , it will not allowed to call the concrete type 's method

That is still not a question... You just stated a fact.

@Sweeper but as my code , the  obj is a existential type value , it can call a concrete type 's method printCar

No it is calling the method printCar you defined in the protocol.

@Sweeper ,maybe because the printCar is defined in the protocol , so it can be called . But another question , I think this obj is a existential type not the concrete type , but the lldb print says like it's a concrete type , is there any better way to get its actual type in lldb ?

Of course obj is a concrete type, it has to be since you can't instantiate a protocol

@JoakimDanielson if it's a concrete type , and  add a function printCar2 directly in SportsCar (not in the Car protocol) ,  this printCar2 can not be called in the obj , so I think this obj is not a concrete type like obj = SportCar()

That is correct and maybe we just use the English language differently but for me the generateSportsCar returns an object that conforms to the Car protocol but that object is always an instance of a concrete type.

Okay, now "is there any better way to get its actual type in lldb?" is an actual question. Please edit your post to actually ask that.

@Sweeper OK ,thanks , I have edit the content

lldb is just trying to be helpful here by "opening" the existential wrapper. and showing you the concrete type. After all, when debugging, knowing the concrete type that a variable stores is much more useful. You already know obj is an existential type at compile time, so it would not be useful for a debugger to tell you the same thing.

and I can even call the method of SportsCar with obj

I suppose you mean that you can call obj.printCar(). You can do that because printCar is declared in Car. On the other hand, if SportsCar declared extra methods of its own, you will not be able to call them.

is there any better way to get its actual type in lldb?

You can write some Python to inspect the actual value of obj, without opening the existential:
(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()'.
>>> obj = lldb.frame.FindVariable("obj")
>>> obj.GetStaticValue()
(Foo.Car) obj = {
  payload_data_0 = 0x00000001ec707148 _swiftEmptySetSingleton
  payload_data_1 = 0x0000000014110001
  payload_data_2 = 0x0000000000000000
  metadata = Any.Type
  wtable = 0x0000000102a99768 Foo`protocol witness table for Foo.SportsCar : Foo.Car in Foo
}

Here you can clearly see that the type is Foo.Car (Foo is the module in which I have declared Car), and its contents contains a witness table for the protocol requirements. This is what the "guts" of an existential type look like.
You can also find something similar with obj.GetType(). It shows the "opened", concrete type information, in addition to the existential type information.
>>> obj.GetType()
Dynamic:
Source code info:
struct SportsCar : Foo.Car {
  func printCar()
  init()
}
Static:
Source code info:
protocol Car {
  func printCar()
}

As an exercise, try running these functions when obj is declared as let obj = SportsCar(), and compare the differences.

excellent  answer,thanks  for your patience .and sorry for my poor English description again

Using an existential type does not implement type erasure. Declaring a variable/return type/input argument as an existential type (any Protocol) simply hides the concrete conforming type, it does not erase its type information. You can get the concrete type at runtime as you've noticed - this is all expected and correct.
To completely hide the concrete type of an existential, you manually need to implement type erasure. If you do implement type erasure, the underlying type is completely lost and can't be retrieved even in the runtime.
See Swift is there still a use case for type erasure since the introduction of primary associated types for more information about when to use type erasure and how to implement it.

Thanks @Dávid Pásztor , But in my code , I think obj is a existential type value , why I can call method with  existential type value , should not the concrete type detail be hided already?

@ximmyxiao You can call printCar() on it, not just because SportsCar implements it, but because it's a requirement of the Car protocol. The whole point of existential types is to provide you uniform-but-opaque access to all the methods required by an initializer
